# Automatic counter as a subclass of integer?

Tags: python, subclass

Is it possible to create a class of integer where an instance of a certain class (say `AutomaticCounter`) will increase itself by some number (say 1) each time it is called?

```
>>> n = AutomaticCounter(start=0)
>>> print(n)
1
>>> print(n)
2
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class AutomaticCounter(int):
    def __init__(self):
        self = 0
    def __str__(self):
        self = self + 1
        return self
```

Comment: You can make a class that will return a different integer each time you print it, but you can't make an int increase its value.

Comment: What's the use case for this?  The reason I ask is, in my opinion, it's generally a bad idea to subclass immutable built-ins.

Comment: When, exactly, do you want its value to increase? Only when it is passed to `print`? Any time it's used in another expression? You would be better off being *explicit* and using something like `itertools.count`, which produces an *iterator* that gives you a new value every time you request one via `next` or during iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really, *really*, ***really*** need to mangle an **immutable** and **built-in** type, then you can create a kind-of "pointer" to it:

```py
class AutomaticCounter(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # create a new instance of int()
        self = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # create a member "ptr" and storing a ref to the instance
        self.ptr = self
        # return the normal instance
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        # first, create a copy via int()
        # which "decays" from your subclass to an ordinary int()
        # then stringify it to obtain the normal __str__() value
        value = str(int(self.ptr))

        # afterwards, store a new instance of your subclass
        # that is incremented by 1
        self.ptr = AutomaticCounter(self.ptr + 1)
        return value

n = AutomaticCounter(0)
print(n)  # 0
print(n)  # 1
print(n)  # 2

# to increment first and print later, use this __str__() instead:
    def __str__(self):
        self.ptr = AutomaticCounter(self.ptr + 1)
        return str(int(self.ptr))
```

This, however, doesn't make the type immutable per se. If you do `print(f"{self=}")` at the beginning of `__str__()` you'll see the instance is unchanged, so you effectively have a size of 2x `int()` (+ some trash) for your object and you access the real instance via `self.ptr`.

It wouldn't work with `self` alone as `self` is merely a read-only reference (created via `__new__()`) passed to instance's methods as the first argument, so something like this:

```py
def func(instance, ...):
    instance = <something else>
```

and you doing the assignment would, as mentioned by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8075540/), simply assign a new value to the **local** variable named `instance` ([`self` is just a quasi-standard name for the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-self)) which doesn't really change the instance. Therefore the next solution which looks similar would be a pointer and as you'd like to manipulate it the way you described, I "hid" it to a custom member called `ptr`.

---

As pointed out by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/), there is a desynchronization caused by the instance being immutable, therefore if you choose the `self.ptr` hack, you'll need to update the magic methods (`__*__()`), for example this is updating the `__add__()`. Notice the `int()` calls, it converts it to `int()` to prevent recursions.

```py
class AutomaticCounter(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ptr = self
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        value = int(self.ptr)
        self.ptr = AutomaticCounter(int(self.ptr) + 1)
        return str(value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        value = other
        if hasattr(other, "ptr"):
            value = int(other.ptr)
        self.ptr = AutomaticCounter(int(self.ptr) + value)
        return int(self.ptr)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        # [1, 2, 3] * your_object
        return other * int(self.ptr)

n = AutomaticCounter(0)
print(n)    # 0
print(n)    # 1
print(n)    # 2
print(n+n)  # 6
```

However, anything that attempts to pull the raw value or tries to access it with C API will most likely fail, namely reverse operations e.g. with immutable built-ins should be the case as for those you can't edit the magic methods reliably so it's corrected in all modules and all scopes.

Example:

```py
# will work fine because it's your class
a <operator> b -> a.__operator__(b)
vs
# will break everything because it's using the raw value, not self.ptr hack
b <operator> a -> b.__operator__(a)
```

with exception of `list.__mul__()` for some reason. When I find the code line in CPython, I'll add it here.

---

Or, a more sane solution would be to create a custom and mutable object, create a member in it and manipulate that. Then return it, stringified, in `__str__`:

```py
class AutomaticCounter(int):
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.item = start
    def __str__(self):
        self.item += 1
        return str(self.item)
```

Comment: This only applies when its called for its string representation, `n = n + 1` wouldn't increase the counter

Comment: @DanielWalker yes, edited

Comment: That, and this desynchronizes the `self.item` value and the actual value of the object as an integer. After `x = AutomaticCounter()` (and after fixing the missing `str` call), `print(x, x, x)` will print `1 2 3`, but if you `print(x+x)` after that, you'll get `0`, because the integer value of `x` is still 0.

Comment: I would avoid subclassing `int`.  Instead, I'd define a `__getattr__` method to pass attribute calls to `self.item`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Desync fixed :)

Comment: Not fixed. Even overriding every relevant magic method can't fix this approach, because most C code that interacts with ints will go through mechanisms like [`PyLong_AsLong`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsLong) that access the integer value directly, and you can't override that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, that's why the type is immutable and accessing the real `self` value will still desync it. Then again, OP doesn't mention any C implementation, just pure Python.

Comment: Large parts of the Python standard library are written in C. You don't need any custom C code to run into problems.

Comment: That includes stuff like `[1, 2, 3] * your_object`, which will use the actual int value.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Nah. Even the example you've provided uses `__rmul__()` and any field operation based of Python objects will use the magic methods. Only once you access it from C API it'll use the C values and even then it'll call the magic methods.

Comment: @PeterBadida: Apparently there's something weird with `list.__mul__` that causes the operation to use `__rmul__`. I'm not sure what's up with that. Try it with `2.5 * your_object` and it'll ignore your `__rmul__` and use `float.__mul__`, and `float.__mul__` will access the int value directly.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Are you sure? See the edit, works fine for me on Python `3.8.10`. Ah, you're right, perhaps it's prioritized as otherwise it'd need to know what members to multiply, etc, which might be missing in the default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  First, `self` isn't actually the object but rather a variable reference **to** the object.  When you reassign `self`, you're not changing the object but merely causing the `self` variable, which only has local scope, to now reference some other object.  The original object remains unchanged.

Second, unless you **really** know what you're doing (and I don't), it is, in my opinion, unadvisable to subclass immutable built-ins.  What you can do is have the object have an integer attribute and then define the `__getattr__` method to pass any attribute calls on to the integer.

```py
class AutomaticCounter:
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.item = start

    def __str__(self):
        self.item += 1
        return str(self.item)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.item, attr)
```